# Where is lint.py file for installing Pylinter on SublimeText

Tags: sublimetext2, pylint

I am trying to install the Pylinter plugin per many online suggestions. They all mention pointing to the lint.py path. I have searched all over and cannot find where this is. I am using Windows and have searched the OS and cannot find it.

Comment: http://www.pylint.org/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I strongly suggest checking out [SublimeLinter](https://github.com/SublimeLinter/SublimeLinter), available through [Package Control](http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/package_control). It has built-in support for many languages, including excellent coverage for Python, and for many linters doesn't require any external programs. It is also very configurable, with several different icon sets for gutter marks and many config options including language mapping (e.g., `"Python Django"` is mapped to `"python"`), setting delays, and options to choose when linting takes place. I highly recommend it over PyLint.

Comment: What are the big differences between it and PyLinter?

Comment: It SublimeLinter for now doesn't support Sublime 3

Comment: if sublime doens't start anymore because of this error, open this file: C:\Users\{{user}}\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 2\Packages\Pylinter\Pylinter.sublime-settings and add this path: "pylint_path": "C:/Python27/Lib/site-packages/pylint/lint.py",

Answer (score 5):

I think you should install pylint for python first.
This url may be help https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pylint.
After installing the pylint, you can find the lint.py in the created directory.

Answer (score 5):

For future users with similar issues like this very one:

Sounds like you added it to Sublime Text without installing it...

Assuming everything else is installed, you should be able to remove it from the terminal.

`pip install pylint`

It should immediately assign and remove the error.

Answer (score 1):

I found mine at C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\pylint\lint.py. Watch out if you've got multiple Python installations though, mine went to Anaconda and I couldn't find it for ages...